# Is it possible to point tox to pull a dependency from a branch (aka use `pip -e` behind the scenes)?

Tags: pytest, pypi, tox

## How to test on py27 and py37 in tox when the py37 changes aren't packaged to pypi

- The py3.7 compatible changes exist in repo branches.
- They can be run by hand through pip -e installing them and running pytest without tox.
- I'd like to move to running them through tox, but I can't figure out the correct string to give the deps list, or perhaps this is done in another way.

Attempted solution:

tox.ini

```
[tox]
envlist = py27,py37


[testenv:py27]
deps =
    pytest
    pytest-cov
    pytest-mock
    pylint
    ; packages specified by the setup.py cover the other dependencies for py2.7
commands =
    pytest -v


[testenv:py37]
deps =
    pytest
    pytest-cov
    pytest-mock
    pylint
    git+ssh//repo_url/location1.git@branchname_that_supports_py37
    git+ssh//repo_url/location2.git@branchname_that_supports_py37
    git+ssh//repo_url/location3.git@branchname_that_supports_py37
    git+ssh//repo_url/location4.git@branchname_that_supports_py37
    git+ssh//repo_url/location5.git@branchname_that_supports_py37
    git+ssh//repo_url/location6.git@branchname_that_supports_py37
    git+ssh//repo_url/location7.git@branchname_that_supports_py37
    git+ssh//repo_url/location8.git@branchname_that_supports_py37

commands =
    pytest -v
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For VCS URLs `pip` needs to know the name of the package that should be provided with `#egg=name`:

```
    git+ssh//repo_url/location1.git@branchname_that_supports_py37#egg=package1
```

Otherwise your `tox.ini` looks good. I [use](https://github.com/sqlobject/sqlobject/blob/ee26d9787b276686f5be9a19229134f3256e24a3/tox.ini#L23) the same approach, for example.

Comment: Ah I see. I had strong suspicions the pip command itself was wrong, but the fact you can pip -e <local_url> without the #egg is what was throwing me off. Will confirm then accept, thanks! And awesome link, I really appreciate that.